# How to import an excel file into r-studio

Tags: r, excel

I have tried many different examples to import my excel file into R. But each time I get this error:

> read_excel("CO_COVID_County_Data.xls", sheet = "data")
> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘CO_COVID_County_Data.xls’

This is my code:

```
install.packages("readxl")
library('readxl')
read_excel("CO_COVID_County_Data.xls", sheet = "data")
```

If anyone could give me pointers on how to get my file to load into r, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: your working directory is probably wrong.  Try `getwd()` to see where you are; `list.files()` to see what's there; or use `setwd()` or RStudio menus to set the WD correctly. (This must be a duplicate ... ?)

Comment: Try `read_excel(file.choose(), sheet = "data")` to open an interactive file chooser. You are probably just using the wrong path or file name.